# Is it possible to run a foreign .exe inside your window form?

Tags: c#

Here I am trying to run some window based application(s) inside a window form's panel and allow me to minimize it inside.
i was able to run and minimize inside this "notepad.exe" but not with win apps.

here's my code for reference(working only for notepad):

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);[DllImport("USER32.dll")]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

Process process = Process.Start("someapp.exe");
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, this.panel1.Handle);
MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width - 90, this.Height, true);
```

please kindly tell me if it's possible to achieve and how?

Comment: I would recommend to avoid such things (read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) and also google for "oldnewthing" and "SetParent" in general) to see why. My favourite quote "It is technically legal. ... It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws."

Comment: so basically it's possible but not a good idea right?

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, all you need to do is to replace**

```
process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

**with**

```
Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
```

this is the results
[app1 executes "For test app" several times and minimize them all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Mmw.jpg)